# cannot insert explicit value to identity column INSERT_OFF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I have been working on an asp mvc project for a couple of weeks. I have inserted and deleted stuff from the database through linq using entities with no problem..until now.

I created my project with the default layout. So on the AccountController after the user is registered I want to register the info in my database

```
Client:
IdClient
Name
LastName
```

I ask for this info via a form, and do this:

```
Client client = new Client();
client.Name = model.Name;
client.LastName = model.LastName
storeDB.Clients.Add(client);
storeDB.SaveChanges();

Note that I'm not attempting to insert anything on the IdClient

The class looks like:
public class Client{

  [Key]
   public int IdClient {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

I have inserted in other tables with NO problem but this one throws me a:
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Client' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Client' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I checked and everything on the table looks normal, the identity is ONLY IdClient!! does anybody know why I'm getting this? =S I don't think it has anything to do with the fact that I'm doing this insert in the AccountsController, it doesn't make sense....

**UPDATE:** I inserted to another table and it doesnt mark me that error, i don't understand...I created them the same! I created a database with JUST One table called CLIENT, and it DOES NOT WORK! does anybody know where I can look for the problem? =S

-I **don't** want to insert a value to the identity column, i tried adding a new row on the show table data, i manually introduced values to Name and Last name, clicked ENTER and the row was created, but when I do it through a query it doesn't let me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the primary key on the mapping class. It should have an attribute something like this:

```
    [Column(Storage="_LetterOID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, 
     DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
```

The important bit is the IsDbGenerated=true. If your attribute lacks that, we have found the error! If you're using the designer, just regenerate this class (by deleting the table in the designer and dropping it from the server explorer).

This solved the problem for me, once before.

Comment: I DON'T want to insert into the key value, and I'm not inserting into the key value...is the answer for this? Let me check. I created it with a script not with the classes. Using the EF diagram!!

Answer (score 0):

As Andrei says, check your designer.
Script out the two tables and confirm the table that works does indeed have an identity column.
Try running profiler for both inserts, are they inserting all the columns the same?

Need more info to answer this question.

Comment: It let's me insert it manually in the show table data, does that mean something? =S